# Split multi-lingual string using Regex to uni-lingual tokens

Tags: c#, regex

I want to split a multi-lingual string to uni-lingual tokens using Regex.

for example for this English-Arabic string :

> 'his name was محمد, and his mother name was آمنه.'

The result must be as below:

1. 'his name was '
2. 'محمد,'
3. ' and his mother name was '
4. 'آمنه.'

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Is it always English-Arabic, or do you at least know which scripts are going to occur in your strings?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yes,it's always English-Arabic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not perfect (you definitely need to try it on some real-world examples to see if it fits), but it's a start:

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, 
    @"(?<=\p{IsArabic})    # (if the previous character is Arabic)
    [\p{Zs}\p{P}]+         # split on whitespace/punctuation
    (?=\p{IsBasicLatin})   # (if the following character is Latin)
    |                      # or
    (?<=\p{IsBasicLatin})  # vice versa
    [\s\p{P}]+
    (?=\p{IsArabic})", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

This splits on whitespace/punctuation if the preceding character is from the Arabic block and the following character is from the Basic Latin block (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"([\s\(\:]*[a-zA-Z]+[\s\)\:]*)+");
var matchs = regx.Matches(input).Cast<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>().ToList();
```

Comment: This expression omits all arabic tokens!